# Issues with returning Axios in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, promise

I am using Axios in my project, and I would like to export the axios function so I can use it in my vue file.

But whenever I use it, it always says that .then() is undefined. I think I know why, because I return the Axios within an async function.

But how can I use .then() to get and use the response in the vue file.

my vue code:

```
        stopAll(){
            startmeetingApi.stop().then((res) => {
                this.transcript = res.data.transcript;
            });
            console.log(this.transcript);
            // this.$router.go();

        },
```

The startmeetingApi.stop method is located in an external file:

```
    stop(){
        recorder.stop().getMp3().then(([buffer, blob]) => {
            const file = new File(buffer, 'test.mp3', {
                type: blob.type,
                lastModified: Date.now()
            });

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("data", file);

            return Axios.post("http://voice-app.test/api/v1/file", formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("Bearer")}`,
                }
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.error(e);
            })

        }).catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
        })
    }
```

for reference, this is the error I got:  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then

Many thanks.

Comment: You should always return a promise that is supposed to be chained. This is not so for some function that you use, and it's unknown which one, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  "I think I know why, because I return the Axios within an async function" - no, it's not because of that.

Comment: @EstusFlask I am not sure what you are referring to. These are all the functions I use. Which part are you referring to?

Comment: These functions aren't listed - startmeetingApi.stop and getMp3.

Comment: The startmeetingapi.stop is listed in the 2nd codeblock. @EstusFlask

Comment: the getmp3 is an external method from a npm package.

Comment: stopAll is listed, not stop. If it's the same function, currently only you know about that. stopAll doesn't return a promise. If it's really called then it's that simple. It's unknown which package. Again, please, provide MCVE for code-related questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EstusFlask stop is listed, atleast for me. It's the method that starts with 'recorder.stop()'

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am kinda new to this part of JavaScript. The "recorder.stop().getmp3() are from an external package.

Comment: I see. Should be `return recorder.stop()`. If you don't return something from a function, you can't use it. Always return a promise, unless proven otherwise.

Comment: @EstusFlask that worked. That also makes so much sense haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to return recorder.stop..

thanks all!